# How do I get one address to go to another on my web server?

Tags: redirect

I'm not sure if this is called "redirecting" but what I'm trying to do is set up a web server to automatically forward one address to another.

For example:
http://www.homeserver.com/hi/    actually redirects the user to http://www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

It is. httpd has the [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive for simple cases like this, or you can use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) if you need something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Make this your default document..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://gohereinstead.com">
</HEAD>
</html>
```

Comment: Techinically speaking, this solution would work. It's not the most desirable, though, due to needing to maintain a DocumentRoot and single html file for the vhost. Ignacio's solution above does not require a DocumentRoot.